# Keep data after deleting object in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has a M2M with another model. Like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ManyToManyField("Author")
```

I want to keep the data in the intermediate table even if I delete an object from `Author` which was added to a `Book` object. Much like the Foreign Key field has the `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`.

I don't think Django has this 'feature'.

**Every time I execute Author.objects.all().delete(), the field author from Books becomes empty. I don't want them to be empty. I want to keep the data prior to delete().**

The reason I want to do this is because I receive a feed and I do a summary on this feed. I delete the objects from author because they might be updated and I don't want to keep checking the data. It's easier to delete and the data is not supposed to change the PK's.

Comment: If you want to keep the data you had prior to delete, don't delete it. Your statement in bold, as I understand it, is impossible by the definition of what delete does.  You should update the objects you already have stored and retrieve them if necessary.

Comment: @Neelik, NOTHING is impossible. It's just a matter of time, effort and resources available. I'm working on one solution and I'll post if it works...

Comment: I'd be curious to see your solution. My suggestion would be adding a post save signal to the Author model which can communicate that change to your feed. This would allow you to maintain up to date information and prevent deletion. I am curious as to why, in your situation, deletion is necessary?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it's handy. I don't have to check for updates in some parts of the data. I receive a daily feed that is pretty big (100MB+) and I just do a bunch of ETL to summarize and make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.

First, I created one intermediate table

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey("Author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  book = models.ForeignKey("Book", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I replaced the Book with the correct new field

```
class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ManyToManyField("Author", through="Inventory")
```

I repopulate the data using the new intermediate table.

Now the fun part:

Before deleting the data, I ran the following command to save my data:

```
./manage.py dumpdata myapp.Inventory > myinventory.json
```

Then, I deleted my Author/Book's data with

```
Author.objects.all().delete()
Book.objects.all().delete()
```

I recreated my data with my ETL and ran the following command

```
./manage.py loaddata myinventory.json
```

And voilà! Fresh data back again!